# Haskell performance—topological sort is not fast enough

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner and have chosen it to solve a programming task for my class, however my solution is too slow and doesn't get accepted. I'm trying to profile it and was hoping that I could get some pointers from more advanced Haskellers here.

The only other solution in my class that got accepted so far was written in Rust. I'm sure that I should be able to achieve similar performance in Haskell and I wrote horrible imperative code in the hope of improving performance, alas to no avail.

My first suspicion relates to `work`, where I am using `forever` to go over the in-degree array until I get an out-of-bounds exception. I was hoping for this to be tail-recursive and to compile to a `while (true)` style loop.

My second suspicion is that I/O is perhaps slowing things down.

EDIT: The problem has likely to do with my algorithm because I am not keeping a queue of nodes with indegree 0. Thank you @luqui.

EDIT2: It seems that the real bottleneck was I/O, I fixed that thanks to @Davislor.

The task is based on this: http://www.spoj.com/UKCPLAD/problems/TOPOSORT/ and I am constrained to use only the libraries in the Haskell Platform.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O3 #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.IORef
import Data.Int
import Control.Exception

type List = []
type Node = Int32
type Edge = (Node, Node)
type Indegree = Int32

main = do
  (numNodes, _) <- readPair <$> getLine
  edges <- map readPair . lines <$> getContents
  topo numNodes edges

-- lower bound
{-# INLINE lb #-}
lb = 1

topo :: Node -> List Edge -> IO ()
topo numNodes edges = do
    result <- newIORef []
    count <- newIORef 0
    indegrees <- newArray (lb,numNodes) 0 :: IO (IOUArray Node Indegree)
    neighbours <- newArray (lb,numNodes) [] :: IO (IOArray Node (List Node))
    forM_ edges $ \(from,to) -> do
      update indegrees to (+1)
      update neighbours from (to:)
    let work = forever $ do
          z <- getNext indegrees
          modifyIORef' result (z:)
          modifyIORef' count (+1)
          ns <- readArray neighbours z
          forM_ ns $ \n -> update indegrees n pred
    work `catch`
      \(_ :: SomeException) -> do
        count <- readIORef count
        if numNodes == count
          then (mapM_ (\n -> putStr (show n ++ " ")) . reverse) =<< readIORef result
          else putStrLn "Sandro fails."


{-# INLINE update #-}
update a i f = do
  x <- readArray a i
  writeArray a i (f x)

{-# INLINE getNext #-}
getNext indegrees = getNext' indegrees =<< getBounds indegrees

{-# INLINE getNext' #-}
getNext' indegrees (lb,ub) = readArray indegrees lb >>= \case
    0 -> writeArray indegrees lb (-1) >> return lb
    _ -> getNext' indegrees (lb+1,ub)

readPair :: String -> (Node,Node)
{-# INLINE readPair #-}
readPair = toPair . map read . words
  where toPair [x,y] = (x,y)
        toPair _ = error "Only two entries per line allowed"
```

Example output

```
$ ./topo
8 9
1 4
1 2
4 2
4 3
3 2
5 2
3 5
8 2
8 6
^D
1 4 3 5 7 8 2 6
```

Comment: What is "fast enough"? Can you bundle this with a self timing test?  What is the algorithm? Is changing the algorithm an option?

Comment: Just for reference, `-O3` does not mean "make it *even faster* than `-O`", it means "try some optimizations which might work but also might slow things down".  `-O` is often the best bet.  Also I don't understand how you are able to `./topo2.hs` -- was that just a typo, or do you have some binding with `runhaskell` which I believe runs in interpreted mode?  You should definitely compile to a native executable.

Comment: Also, if you can add the non-imperative version that would help.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I added some more info above. I'm currently toying around with profiling.

Comment: @luqui Thanks for that info. I compiled it to native code using `stack ghc -- topo.hs` but in that example I'm running it in interpreted mode. The version which doesn't pass the online judge is definitely compiled.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I don't know what a purely functional version could look like really, because this algorithm relies on O(1) indexing into an array and in-place updates.

Comment: Also on the surface this algorithm looks O(n^2), because `getNext` does a linear search, and you do it once per output node. I don't know where the log n would come from, unless there is something subtle going on in the analysis.   Also recursive functions won't be inlined even if you ask them to.

Comment: You could improve the algorithm by keeping a running queue of nodes with indegree 0.  Each time you decrement the indegree of a node, if it has indegree 0 add it to this queue.  That would remove the linear search for such nodes in `getNext`.  If you use `Data.Set` for this queue then your sorted requirement will be met and also I believe the algorithm will actually become O(n log n) because set insertion is log n.

Comment: @luqui Indeed, I made a blunder. Thanks!

Comment: @luqui, `IntSet` is (usually) better than `Set`. I wonder if it would make sense to store each neighbor list in an `IntSet`. Would you still need a set for the queue itself then?

Comment: Also, `-O3` isn't actually a thing for GHC; it just does the same as `-O2`.

Comment: @dfeuer using `IntSet` instead of `Set` decreased execution time quite dramatically from 2.36 seconds to 1.83 on the example test cases, so it's now quite close to what the Rust people are getting, although it's not quite there yet. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven’t already, [profile your program](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) by compiling with `-prof -fprof-auto` and then executing with the command-line options `+RTS -p`.  This will generate a profile `*.prof` that will tell you which functions the program is spending all its time in.  However, I can see immediately where the biggest time-waster is.  Your instincts were right: it’s the I/O.

Having done that a lot, I can guarantee you that you’ll find that it’s spending the vast majority of its time doing I/O.  The first thing you should always do to speed up your program is rewrite it to use fast I/O.  Haskell is a fast language, *when you use the right data structures.*  The default I/O library in the Prelude uses singly-linked lists with lazily-evaluated thunks where each node holds a single Unicode character.  That would be slow in C, too!

I’ve gotten the best results with `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` when the input is ASCII, and `Data.ByteString.Builder` to generate the output.  (An alternative is `Data.Text`.)  That gets you a lazily-evaluated list of strict character buffers on input (so interactive input and output still works), and fills a single buffer on output.

After you’ve written the skeleton of the program with fast I/O, the next step is to look at your algorithm, and especially your data structures.  Use profiling to see where all the time goes.  But I’d recommend you use a functional algorithm rather than trying to write imperative programs in Haskell with `do`.

I almost always approach problems like this in Haskell with a more functional style: in particular, my `main` function is almost always something similar to:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8

main :: IO()
main = B8.interact ( output . compute . input )
```

This makes everything except the call to `interact` a pure function, and isolates the parsing code and the formatting code so the `compute` part in the middle can be independent of that.

Since this is an assignment and you want to solve the problem yourself, I’ll refrain from refactoring the program for you, but here’s an example I wrote in response to a question on another forum to perform a counting sort.  It should be suitable as a skeleton for other kinds of problems.

```
import Data.Array.IArray (accumArray, assocs)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray)
import Data.ByteString.Builder (Builder, char7, intDec, toLazyByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

main :: IO()
main = B8.interact ( output . compute . input ) where
  input :: B8.ByteString -> [Int]
  input = map perLine . tail . B8.lines where
    perLine = decode . B8.readInt

    decode (Just (x, _)) = x
    decode Nothing = error "Invalid input: expected integer."

  compute :: [Int] -> [Int]
  compute = concatMap expand . assocs . countingSort . map encode where
    encode i = (i, 1)

    countingSort :: [(Int, Int)] -> UArray Int Int
    countingSort = accumArray (+) 0 (lower, upper)

    lower = 0
    upper = 1000000

    expand (i,c) = replicate c i

  output :: [Int] -> B8.ByteString
  output = toLazyByteString . foldMap perCase where
    perCase :: Int -> Builder
    perCase x = intDec x <> char7 '\n'
```

At present, this version ran in less than half the time of anyone else’s [Haskell solution for the same problem](https://www.codechef.com/status/TSORT?sort_by=Time&sorting_order=asc&language=21&status=15&handle=), the same holds true for the actual contest problems I’ve used it for, and [the approach generalizes](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/38114/is-it-possible-to-solve-tsort-with-haskell).

So I suggest changing the I/O to be similar to that, first, then profiling, and coming back with the profiling output if that doesn’t make enough of a difference.  This might also be a good Code Review question.

Comment: I’d appreciate hearing why you downvoted, so I can improve the answer?

Comment: I can't see that anyone downvoted this. I just accepted it as the answer to my question. Thank you indeed! I will put my code in a follow up question below.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! One other person didn’t. Oh well.

Comment: I will admit to being the downvoter. I didn't like the fact that you seemed to point to I/O instinctively, despite the fact that there was an algorithmic complexity problem. I also didn't particularly appreciate the large piece of code for solving a completely different problem. I'm glad your answer proved helpful to the OP, though.

Comment: Very helpful indeed, especially the code snippet. The algorithmic complexity hardly mattered, rather surprisingly.

Comment: @dfeuer My experience with profiling other code like this is that the `Prelude` I/O is extremely slow, dominates the runtime, and always needs to be changed first. And I didn’t want to write a solution myself, but I did want to give a MCVE of a simpler problem. It took me a lot of trial and error to work out that skeleton for fast I/O.

Comment: In other words, fast I/O is a necessary but not sufficient condition to solve just about any contest problem in Haskell. And it was not at all obvious to me how to write it.

Comment: @dfeuer I think I will cut back on the discussion of the other problem though, and just leave the one example.

Comment: some exercise sites put a very strict time constraint to the exercise, you can have the best possible solution and still not pass because of the IO not being fast enough. This answer really solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Davislor's suggestions I managed to get it to be **much** faster and I also refactored the code for the better and now I actually have an *m* log(*n*) algorithm. Surprisingly this doesn't make that much of a difference—the I/O far outweighed the suboptimal complexity of the algorithm.

EDIT: got rid of `unsafePerformIO` and it actually runs a teeny-weeny bit faster. Plus adding `-XStrict` shaves off even more time.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Int
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.ByteString.Builder (Builder, char7, intDec, toLazyByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8
import Data.Monoid ((<>))


type List = []
type Node = Int
type Edge = (Node, Node)
type Indegree = Int

main = B8.putStrLn =<< topo . map readPair . B8.lines =<< B8.getContents

readPair :: B8.ByteString -> (Node,Node)
readPair str = (x,y)
  where
    (Just (x, str')) = B8.readInt str
    (Just (y, _   )) = B8.readInt (B8.tail str')

topo :: List Edge -> IO B8.ByteString
topo inp = do
    let (numNodes, _) = head inp
        edges         = tail inp
    indegrees <- newArray (1,numNodes) 0 :: IO (IOUArray Node Indegree)
    neighbours <- newArray (1,numNodes) [] :: IO (IOArray Node (List Node))

    -- setup
    forM_ edges $ \(from,to) -> do
      update indegrees to (+1)
      update neighbours from (to:)

    zeroes <- collectIndegreeZero [] indegrees =<< getBounds indegrees
    processQueue (Set.fromList zeroes) [] numNodes indegrees neighbours

  where
    collectIndegreeZero acc indegrees (lb,ub)
      | lb > ub = return acc
      | otherwise = do
          indegr <- readArray indegrees lb
          let acc' = if indegr == 0 then (lb:acc) else acc
          collectIndegreeZero acc' indegrees (lb+1,ub)

    processQueue queue result numNodes indegrees neighbours = do
        if null queue
          then if numNodes == 0
              then return . toLazyByteString . foldMap whitespace . reverse $ result
              else return "Sandro fails."
          else do
            (node,queue) <- return $ Set.deleteFindMin queue
            ns <- readArray neighbours node
            queue <- foldM decrIndegrees queue ns
            processQueue queue (node:result) (numNodes-1) indegrees neighbours
      where
        decrIndegrees :: Set Node -> Node -> IO (Set Node)
        decrIndegrees q n = do
            i <- readArray indegrees n
            writeArray indegrees n (i-1)
            return $ if i == 1 then Set.insert n q else q

        whitespace x = intDec x <> char7 ' '

{-# INLINE update #-}
update a i f = do
  x <- readArray a i
  writeArray a i (f x)
```

Comment: No, that's not a legit reason to use `unsafePerformIO`. You should perform your calculation in `ST` instead (using `STArray` rather than `IOArray`) and then just `runST` it.

Comment: Well, you saw what I did instead of `unsafePerformIO`. This is a great illustration of Amdahl’s Law. You have to optimize the tasks that actually take all the time, and if you profile a program that uses the `Prelude` I/O functions, you’ll see that that’s what takes so long.

Comment: @Davislor, I don't *think* the pure `Array` interface is going to be sufficient to solve this problem efficiently. The array isn't just filled and then used read-only; it needs to be mutated throughout as the output list is generated.

Comment: The suggestion to use a `STArray` instead is a good one. (`Data.Vector` is also good if you have it available.) I would also recommend changing some of those other `do` blocks of imperative code to functional versions, but that’s more a stylistic choice.

Comment: @dfeuer I do have some other code samples online that I can give as an example of `STArray`, if the OP wants. But, yes, contest problems generally do require mutability so you can’t just use square-root decomposition and the like, and mutable arrays are the data structure Haskell is worst at.

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` was actually completely unnecessary... @Davislor, yes I would like to see that!

Comment: Here’s one example: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/16169749 (Problem statement: https://www.codechef.com/NOV17/problems/CSUBQ/). That’s only a partly-accepted solution, because there was a solution with better algorithmic complexity, but it does demonstrate one way to use `STArray`.